# Basic operations (+/*) of naturals and prove their commutativity and associativity - Dafny

Tags: dafny

Learning Dafny I want to define over naturals (as an algebraic data type) sum and multiplication of naturals and prove their commutativity and associativity.

What I managed to do:

Addition

```
datatype Nat = Zero | Succ(Pred: Nat)

function add(m: Nat, n: Nat) : Nat
decreases m
{
    match m
    case Zero => n
    case Succ(m') => Succ(add(m', n))
}
```

Multiplication

```
function multiply(m: Nat, n: Nat) : Nat
decreases n
{
    match n
    case Zero => Zero
    case Succ(Zero) => m
    case Succ(p) => add(m, multiply(m, p))
}
```

Addition Commutativity

```
lemma CommAdd(m: Nat, n: Nat)
ensures add(m,n) == add(n, m)
{
    match m
    case Zero => Add1(n);
    case Succ(m') => CommAdd(m', n);
}
```

Where I got stuck:

Multiplication Commutativity, Associativity, here is what I tried but doesn't get "verified".

```
// Neutral element
lemma Multiply1(m: Nat)
decreases m
// ensures multiply(m, Zero) == Zero
ensures multiply(m, Succ(Zero)) == m
{
//
}


// Commutativity of Multiplication - DRAFT, NOT VERIFIED
lemma CommMult(m: Nat, n: Nat)
ensures multiply(m, n) == multiply(n, m)
{
    match m
    case Zero => Zero
    case Succ(Zero) => Multiply1(n)
    case Succ(m') => CommMult(m', n)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that your definition of `multiply` pattern match on second argument, where as your proof `CommMult` pattern match on first argument. Though it is possible to prove using either way it is much easier if both agree.

```
function multiply(m: Nat, n: Nat): Nat
  decreases m
{
  match m
    case Zero => Zero
    case Succ(Zero) => n
    case Succ(p) => add(n, multiply(p, n))
}
lemma CommMult(m: Nat, n: Nat)
  ensures multiply(m, n) == multiply(n, m)
{
  match m
    case Zero => {}
    case Succ(Zero) => Multiply1(n);
    case Succ(m') => CommMult(m', n);
}
```

Now `Succ(Zero)` branch doesn't throw verification error. **Further note that it is match statement which is different from match expression.** In `Zero` case dafny is able to verify automatically, reason statement is empty. In `Succ(Zero)` case lemma `Multiply1(n)` is enough to prove postcondition. `Succ(m')` branch needs further lemmas / statements to prove. `CommMult(m', n)` gives `multiply(m', n) == multiply(n, m')`, but it also requires distributive property of multiplication over addition to finish the proof.

```
   m * n 
== S m' * n
== n + m' * n
{ using CommMulti property}
== n + n * m'
{ using distributive property }
== n * (1 + m')
== n * m
```

This calculation style proof is supported by dafny in form of `calc`

```
lemma CommMult(m: Nat, n: Nat)
  ensures multiply(m, n) == multiply(n, m)
{
  match m
    case Zero => {}
    case Succ(Zero) => Multiply1(n);
    case Succ(m') => {
      calc {
        multiply(Succ(m'), n);
        // defintion of multiply
        add(n, multiply(m', n));
        { CommMult(m', n); }
        add(n, multiply(n, m'));
        { Multiply1(n); }
        add(multiply(n, Succ(Zero)), multiply(n, m'));
        // TODO use distributive law
      }
    }
}
```